# server_address usage in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, wss

Could someone help me understand the following **python websocket** code?

In particular I am interested in the **server_address** initialization. Does '' match to localhost by **default**? If not how can I get that to be localhost?

```
import socket
import sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('', 8080)
sock.bind(server_address)
```

Comment: No. `''` is the equivalent to `0.0.0.0`, which would be *any* address. If you want to bind it to just localhost, then specify that -> `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Haven't tested it out but the keyword 'localhost' should work too technically.

Comment: ok, so I have run the code and I am trying to connect to the server from a client app using ws. Which address should I give then? ws://0.0.0.0:8080?